# Replace string within a variable in R using fuzzy matching

Tags: r, text-mining, matching

I have data with 3 relevant variables: The first is an activity (x1), the second is the respondents rating of that activity (x2), and the third is the proper name of the activity in x1 (x3).  The x1 variables are respondent written, and very close matches to the reference variable of the activity x3, but all a little bit different.  I would like to match and replace all x1's with the reference x3 - I was thinking of using a loop referring to each reference activity x3 and replacing the x1 respondent written activity using a program like agrep.  However, agrep seems only to tell me what the matches are.  How can I replace the x1 variables with the "correct" string title in x3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in R, the function `agrep` returns the indices where it found a match, not the number of matches

```
agrep('chrg', c('charge', 'trapper', 'friend', 'charger'))
# [1] 1 4
```

If you would like to have the value instead of the index, you can pass `value=TRUE`.

```
agrep('chrg', c('charge', 'trapper', 'friend', 'charger'), value=TRUE)
# [1] "charge"  "charger"
```

**EDIT after your update:**

If `x1` and `x3` are in phase (for each index you have the names of the *same* activity) here is a snippet that will do the trick.

```
subs <- function(x, old, new) {
    # Replace 'old' by 'new' in 'x'.
    matchv <- match(x, old, nomatch=0)
    replace(x, matchv > 0, new[matchv])
}
# y is any vector that contains short names.
subs(y, x1, x3)
```

If they are not in phase you can create the `old` and `new` vectors as follows with `agrep`.

```
oldnew <- sapply(x1, function(x) { agrep(x, x3, value=TRUE)[1] })
subs(y, names(oldnew), oldnew)
```

Comment: @gui1aume sorry i did not type the part about agrep correctly, I have fixed it now.  Thanks for the value comment, but I am not looking to see which entries fulfill the criteria - I am looking to replace the values that match criteria with another value.  As stated in the question, I do not think agrep is the command to use, I was just using it as an illustration for the type of fuzzy matching I am looking for.  It is replacing the matches that is the issue.